# GPUImage Memory Leak *Dirty* IOKit Object Hogging Memory

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera

I am using GPUImage and I have a UIViewController which loads a GPUStillImageCamera into fullview.

However if I close and open this UIViewController 5x, then I get a nasty crash.

It's an out of memory crash (since there is no error message) and it's caused by dirty memory.

My Allocations shows only 67mb usage (on an iPhone 6+)
[image]

However the virtual memory tells a different story, saying I've used about 300mb of memory

[image]

The culprit is IOKit at a whopping 182mb (with several other occurrences taking up 10mb+ each in some cases).

Do you have any advice on a workaround for a memory leak like this in GPUImage or where I can look 'deeper' into what this IOKit (78972 pages) object is and where it's coming from?

Comment: I have the same issue as you, if I am using GPUImageFilterGroup and up to 3 filters, it crash. Do you have any solution to this problem?

Comment: Nope, I have no clue